# ArcGIS is not coloring when read from KML file

Tags: arcgis-10.2, kml, google-earth

Here is the beginning of my KML file. When I imported this file into ArcGIS Maps SDK, the points are not being colored with given color. It works perfectly okay on Google Earth.

How can I address this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>106.702061</longitude>
            <latitude>47.886520</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <range>3500</range>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <heading>0</heading>
        </LookAt>
        <Folder>
            <name>PCell Serving RSRP [20230620_1500-M1_LTE-QC_QMICM_SMART_DATA_LTE-DOWN (APP_FTP)__M9]</name>
            <Style id="GCircle0"><IconStyle>
                <color>b55e44ff</color><colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <scale>0.1</scale>
                <Icon><href>URLTHATWORKS</href>
                </Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>00ffffff</color></LabelStyle>
                <LineStyle><color>b55e44ff</color><width>4</width></LineStyle></Style>
            <Style id="GCircle1"><IconStyle>
                <color>b55e44ff</color><colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <scale>0.3</scale>
                <Icon><href>URLTHATWORKS</href>
                </Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>00ffffff</color></LabelStyle>
                <LineStyle><color>ff00ff8a</color><width>4</width></LineStyle></Style>
            <Style id="GCircle2"><IconStyle>
                <color>b55e44ff</color><colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <scale>0.3</scale>
                <Icon><href>URLTHATWORKS</href>
                </Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>00ffffff</color></LabelStyle>
                <LineStyle><color>ff00ffe7</color><width>4</width></LineStyle></Style>
            <Style id="GCircle3"><IconStyle>
                <color>b55e44ff</color><colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <scale>0.3</scale>
                <Icon><href>URLTHATWORKS</href>
                </Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>00ffffff</color></LabelStyle>
                <LineStyle><color>ff2894ff</color><width>4</width></LineStyle></Style>
            <Style id="GCircle4"><IconStyle>
                <color>b55e44ff</color><colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <scale>0.3</scale>
                <Icon><href>URLTHATWORKS</href>
                </Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>00ffffff</color></LabelStyle>
                <LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color><width>4</width></LineStyle></Style>
            <Placemark><name>-80 &lt;= x &lt; -70 (17.01%, 1620)</name><styleUrl>#GCircle0</styleUrl>
                <MultiGeometry>
                    <Point><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>106.731697,47.929008,0.000000</coordinates></Point>
                    <Point><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>106.731567,47.929070,0.000000</coordinates></Point>
                    <Point><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>106.729523,47.930012,0.000000</coordinates></Point>
                    <Point><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>106.729378,47.930161,0.000000</coordinates></Point>
                    <Point><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>106.728958,47.930630,0.000000</coordinates></Point>
                    <Point><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>106.728821,47.930790,0.000000</coordinates></Point>
```

Comment: `<tilt>0</tilt>`is not valid on line 9 ~ `Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":tilt}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":altitudeModeGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":LookAtSimpleExtensionGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":LookAtObjectExtensionGroup}' is expected.`

Comment: The file is just got exported from Google Earth. So I don't think there is problem with the file itself but ArcGIS.

Comment: There is a problem with the file.  It may be that Google Earth doesn't care about the issue and ArcGIS does.

Answer (score -2):

You should use # for example #b55e44ff

Comment: Hi there, could you please give more details for this answer?

Comment: We're looking for Answers which not only offer a fix but also reference documentation or explain why the solution will work. This should take a paragraph or two, not a single sentence.

Comment: There's no requirement in the [KML 2.2 specification](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=27810) used here that says that colours have to be given using that format.  You can see looking at 12.2.4 that the example for `IconStyle` uses `<color>a1ff00ff</color>`